# override customer registration rest api in magento2 and block the domains of a specific emails like @163.com

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Can any one help me to override the customer registration api and restrict the @163.com emails while registering magento2 rest api

Help me great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a before plugin for function `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccount` and get the email address from the `$customer` object then do the domain validation if the validation fails throw some exception.

ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html to create a plugin

Comment: Thanks for your reply sundaram we would like to do it from rest api

Comment: Can you suggest me any overriding process of default rest api to the customer creation

Comment: @VijayKumar Magento has multiple overriding concepts, in that plugin is of the overriding concept. Kindly refer to the above link to get an understanding of that. Also I have mentioned the class and function to write the plugin for.

Comment: Thanks sundaram I  will check it and let you know

Comment: Hi @Meenakshisundaram Is that concept works for rest api overriding process

Comment: Hi @Meenakshisundaram, i have overrided the createAccount() but getting some errors:

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php: 811

Comment: can you please help me out on this